# Flag Change after Target in Makefile

Tags: make

I am seeing a line of makefile as follows:

```
$(LAST_TARGET_DIR)/%: LFLAGS += -lpthread -lrt -Wl,-uevaluate
```

In my understanding, `$(LAST_TARGET_DIR)/%` is a target matching, and after the target should come its dependencies. Why are linking flags changed here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a feature of GNU make that allows using a different value of a variable for one specific [target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html#Target_002dspecific) or [pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern_002dspecific.html#Pattern_002dspecific).

For example,

```
LFLAGS = -lm
$(LAST_TARGET_DIR)/%: LFLAGS += -lpthread

%.exe: %.o common.o
    $(CC) -o $@ common.o $(@:%.exe=%.o) $(LFLAGS)
```

causes every `.exe` file to be linked with `-lm`, except that those in the directory `$(LAST_TARGET_DIR)` will be linked with `-lm -lpthreads`.

Comment: Great. Thanks. GNU make is not an easy system :(